# Why are the widgets stacked on top of each other in the tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-canvas

I have been creating a program in **python using tkinter** and I had this downloads tab that needed a **scrollbar**. After some google searches I found out that it is not quite easy to make a full app scrollable because only a couple of widgets natively support the scrollbar widget. I searched it and found a way, however, when trying to implement it myself, I faced an error. When I use grid with this method, the widgets get stacked up on each other, rather than being on separate rows. I tried doing the same thing with a for loop like the tutorial and the problem was solved but I don't want my program to work with a for loop. Here is the code without the for loop:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

available_row = 0

root = Tk()
root.title("A Scrollbar")
root.geometry("580x308")
# Create a download frame
download_fr = Frame(root, width=580, height=308)
big_lbl = Label(download_fr, text="Just a BIG label. ", font=("Helvetica", "30", "bold"))
prg_br = ttk.Progressbar(download_fr, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')



def pack_bars():
    global available_row
    big_lbl.pack_forget()
    prg_br.pack_forget()
    # Pack the Scrollbar
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    # Configure the canvas
    cnava.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    cnava.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: cnava.configure(scrollregion=cnava.bbox("all")))
    # Create another frame inside the canvas
    second_frame = Frame(cnava)
    # Add that new frame to a window in the canvas
    cnava.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
    ttk.Button(second_frame, text=f"This is the {available_row}th button").grid(row=available_row, column=0)
    available_row += 1
    print(f"Next available row: {available_row}")


btn = Button(download_fr, text="Pack progress bars. ", command=pack_bars)
# Create a canvas
cnava = Canvas(download_fr, bg="red")
# Create a Scrollbar
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(download_fr, orient=VERTICAL, command=cnava.yview)
big_lbl.pack(pady=(85, 5))
prg_br.pack()
prg_br.start(5)
cnava.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
btn.pack()
download_fr.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the same code with a for loop:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.title("A Scrollbar")
root.geometry("580x308")
# Create a download frame
download_fr = Frame(root, width=580, height=308)
big_lbl = Label(download_fr, text="Just a BIG label. ", font=("Helvetica", "30", "bold"))
prg_br = ttk.Progressbar(download_fr, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')


def pack_bars():
    big_lbl.pack_forget()
    prg_br.pack_forget()
    # Pack the Scrollbar
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    # Configure the canvas
    cnava.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    cnava.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: cnava.configure(scrollregion=cnava.bbox("all")))
    # Create another frame inside the canvas
    second_frame = Frame(cnava)
    # Add that new frame to a window in the canvas
    cnava.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
    # Creating a loop to grid 100 buttons
    for i in range(100):
        ttk.Button(second_frame, text=f"This is the {i}th button").grid(row=i, column=0)


btn = Button(download_fr, text="Pack progress bars. ", command=pack_bars)
# Create a canvas
cnava = Canvas(download_fr, bg="red")
# Create a Scrollbar
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(download_fr, orient=VERTICAL, command=cnava.yview)
big_lbl.pack(pady=(85, 5))
prg_br.pack()
prg_br.start(5)
cnava.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
btn.pack()
download_fr.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

It seems like that in the first program, the canvas is nor resizing because the red area is not changing, therefore the buttons are girded on top of each other. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new `second_frame` and put it at the same position in the canvas whenever `pack_bars()` is executed.  You should create the `second_frame` once outside the function.

Also you should bind `<Configure>` on `second_frame` instead of `cnava`.

Below is the modified code based on yours:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

available_row = 0

root = Tk()
root.title("A Scrollbar")
root.geometry("580x308")
# Create a download frame
download_fr = Frame(root, width=580, height=308)
big_lbl = Label(download_fr, text="Just a BIG label. ", font=("Helvetica", "30", "bold"))
prg_br = ttk.Progressbar(download_fr, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')



def pack_bars():
    global available_row
    big_lbl.pack_forget()
    prg_br.pack_forget()
    # Pack the Scrollbar
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    # add a new button to second_frame
    ttk.Button(second_frame, text=f"This is the {available_row}th button").grid(row=available_row, column=0)
    available_row += 1
    print(f"Next available row: {available_row}")


btn = Button(download_fr, text="Pack progress bars. ", command=pack_bars)
# Create a canvas
cnava = Canvas(download_fr, bg="red")
# Create a Scrollbar
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(download_fr, orient=VERTICAL, command=cnava.yview)
cnava.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)

big_lbl.pack(pady=(85, 5))
prg_br.pack()
prg_br.start(5)
cnava.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
btn.pack()
download_fr.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Create another frame inside the canvas
second_frame = Frame(cnava)
# Add that new frame to a window in the canvas
cnava.create_window(0, 0, window=second_frame, anchor='nw')
# update canvas scrollregion whenever the size of second_frame is changed
second_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: cnava.configure(scrollregion=cnava.bbox('all')))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! You were right, I should have defined the frame outside of the function. Why didn't I thought of that myself! You are amazing.